# Can finite-size objects have a point of no return?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

I read all objects have a Schwartzschild radius. Does that mean there is a sphere in finite-size objects beyond which there is no return?

If so, where is it located in our sun, the Earth or our bodies? And what happens if a particle wanders into it?

Comment: I suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Answer (score 0):

The Schwarzschild radius of objects with finite size is actually just a mathematical artifact. The Schwarzschild metric for spherically symmetric and static object with mass $M$ reads as:

$d\tau^2 = \bigg(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\bigg) dt^2 - \dfrac{1}{\bigg(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\bigg)} dr^2 - r^2 d\Omega_2^2$

Now, this metric is valid only for the region outside the mass distribution as it has been obtained by solving vacuum Einstein equations around a spherically symmetric and static object. So, if the physical radius of the spherical object is $R$ then the above metric doesn't apply for $r<R$. Now, the Schwarzschild radius is defined as $r=2M$ and it is dictated by the rules of general relativity that if $R<2M$ then the object will inevitably form a black hole as all of its particles will inevitably reach $r=0$ in a finite proper time. In such a case, the Schwarzschild radius has its well-known behavior. If $R>2M$ then the object persists but the solution itself is not valid at $r=2M$, the defined Schawrzschild radius. Thus, the conclusions drawn about Schwarzschild radius being the boundary of no-return don't apply here as these conclusions can be reached at when the Schwarzschild metric is applicable at and beyond the Schwarzschild radius. So, no - the usual objects like the Earth or a marble don't have a radius inside them marking the boundary of no-return. We can split a marble into exactly two halves - if it had any such no-return radius then it wouldn't be possible!

Comment: In simple terms, the Schwarzschild radius is the size to which the object needs to be compressed to become a black hole. The article linked by @user1583209 shows it for several objects, including sun (about 3 km) and earth (about 1 cm).